# RDCM mouse click rendering

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, mouse-click

so I bought myself a new 24" FHD 16:9 monitors for christmas. before I had a 22" HD 16:10.

When I now connect to one of my servers through Remote Desctop Manager (RDCM) I have some problems with the rendering of my mouse.

**Problem:**
I need to click a few mm right from the target I intend to click

**Settings**
I have set the resolution of rdcm to the resolution of the new desktop. 
1920:1080 16:9 identified by windows as monitor 1(right), the second one is
1680x1050 16:10 identified as 2 (left)

**Example:**

when i intend to click between a and b of the following string I would have to click on the d

"abcdefgh"

**Solution 1:**
When I move the rdcm window to the left(old 16:10) monitor, it is working as expected.
But I would like to use this on the new desktop because it is bigger and right in front.

Thanks for your help and Happy new year